# parse.com object is not saved although the Success method is called

Tags: parse-platform

I have the below Cloud Code to save a user object into the Parse.Installation object he is related to.

I see in the Cloud Code logs that the "Success" callback is called but when I check the Installation object in Parse browser, the "User" attribute is "undefined".

Any ideas?

```
Parse.Cloud.define("saveUserWithInstallationObj", function(request, response) {

  //Get Installation object from installationId
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  query.equalTo("installationId", request.params.installationId);
  query.first({ 
    success: function(result) {
      if(result){       
        var currentUser = new Parse.User({id:request.params.userId});
        result.set("user", currentUser);
        result.save(null, {
          success: function(installation) {
            console.log("******SAVED Installation object");
            response.success();
          },
          error: function(e) {                              
            console.log(e);
            response.error(e.message);
          }
        });
      }else{
        //no results
      }

    },
    error: function(error) {
    }
  });  
});
```

Comment: Double check : 1. *user* column is of type Pointer to User Class. 2. You need to use MASTERKEY for modifications in User/Installation objects.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the "user" parameter in your code, but you're saying the "User" parameter is blank in the dashboard.

Those column headers are case sensitive. What I believe is happening is that you created the "User" column in your dashboard, and your code is populating the "user" column, which didn't exist yet. When you create a new column via code, it doesn't show up until you refresh your entire app, by pressing that down arrow in the top left corner and reselecting your app. You probably saw the new "user" column when you did that.